# Test driven development: How do I not repeat myself on top of the tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have this file as my starting point

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views  
  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "Should have the proper title" do
      @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector( "title",
      :content => "Slacklog")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

But you notice the line

```
      @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
```

This is my basic HTTP authentication and I need this on all my tests but i fee like there has got to be a better way of adding this before all my tests then copying and pasting on top of all the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe PagesController do

  before(:each) do
    @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
  end

  ...

end
```